# What historical figures have been identified as 'Amalek?

Tags: history, historical-figures, amalek, genealogy

Adolf Hitler is often said to have been from 'Amalek. I've even heard it said not only figuratively but literally (how one could know that is a mystery to me).

What other historical figures are associated with 'Amalek, and of those, who was actually known to have been genealogically descended from 'Amalek? Is Haman the last recorded descendant, for example?

Comment: Note that _Haman_'s descent from _Amalek_ is a _midrash_, not _p'shat_. (I mention this because you use the word "recorded".)

Comment: @msh210 TaNa"Ch isn't the only source for our history.

Comment: Wasn't it Rav Soloveitchik who said that Hitler was Amalek?

Comment: @msh210 Haman "Ha'agagi" is rooted in pshat.

Answer (score 6):

As far as more recently recorded descendants, don't forget that the Gemara  (Gitin 57b) says that Haman's descendants taught Torah in Bnei Brak (or small children, depending on which version you follow).

> Although our texts do not reveal who these descendants of Haman and Sisera were, the text available to the early commentators apparently did. The descendant of Sisera was Rebbi Akiva, and the descendant of Haman was **Rav Shmuel bar Shelas**<sup>1</sup>, a contemporary of Rav ([Ein Yakov to Sanhedrin 96b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47605&st=&pgnum=35)<sup>2</sup>; Toldot Tana'im v'Amora'im; Sefer Yuchasin; Menoras ha'Ma'or 5:3:2:3).

[From dafyomi.co.il](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/parsha/purim5.htm)

Ok, so not as recent as one might like, but still...

---

<sup>1: Others reverse the descendants, and say that Rabbi Akiva was descended from Haman instead. No concrete source on this, yet. [Just internet musings.](http://www.aish.com/tp/i/moha/48939037.html)

2: Right at the top right.</sup>

Comment: They converted before that and ceased to be Amalek. So, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: True, but that's not what the question asked. I quote: _"Is Haman the last recorded descendant, for example?"_ Therefore, my answer begins with: _"As far as more recently recorded descendants..."_