# Is bigotry prohibited?

Tags: halacha

I was reading a [recent answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101461/7081) and saw this

> There may also be issues of humiliating a person (see [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Chapter 63](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.63.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which while mostly dealing with business-related deceiving, has several non-business applications)

Having no knowledge on the subject, got me wondering:

Is bigotry prohibited?

Comment: What's "bigotry"? Please better define the action you want to know about.

Comment: But I'm still honored that my answer inspired your question. ;)

Comment: 8 people upvoted my comment, but none voted to close as Unclear. Why?

Comment: @DoubleAA, to be fair, I did vote to close, but for a different reason. :) I've seen this on several other stacks as well, I think that since there's a higher threshold for close voting than upvoting a comment (requires 3k rep to close vote), many people end up voting the comment in lieu of a legitimate close vote. May make an interesting meta discussion to see if there is something to be done about it.

Comment: @DoubleAA By [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigot) it’s a dupe.

Answer (score -8):

Once you divide the world into the good guys and the bad guys, as we're always the good ones, you simply follow ([Teh 97, 10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.97.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)):

> "אֹהֲבֵי ה' שִׂנְאוּ רָע"
>
> "O you who love the LORD, HATE evil!"

And from that point on you're free to treat them as you wish.

Comment: What in God's name is this even supposed to mean??? Please don't respond to this question. It was meant to make a point, not to open a dialog.

Comment: @user6591 Is there something non Halachic in what I said?

Comment: Um, [try again](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44740/9682). Not to mention that the passuk you cite says that we should hate *evil*, not *evildoers*.

Comment: @DonielF Right, the Gemmorah in Brochos I think. But the idea is simple - once you mark something as evil you're free to exterminate it. That's how Judaism works.

Comment: @AlBerko Um, *no*, it’s not. It never was, it never will be.

Comment: @DonielF Would you like to discuss it?

Comment: @AlBerko [It already has been.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81067/) No need to rehash it here.