Are Amalekites considered Edomites Halachically?
According to the opinion that we may accept converts from Amalek, must they wait until the third generation to marry a Jew, as would an Edomite, being that Amalek also comes from Esav?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100636/759

Megillat Sefer believes that Sefer Mitzvot Gadol (lo ta'aseh 115) would allow an Amalekite convert to marry a Jew after three generations, like an Edomite.
He contrasts this with the position of Ramban, who, he believes, would never allow an Amalekite convert to marry a Jew, even after ten generations.
